# run cmd as admin with ActiveXObject javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to run a cmd command as admin. How would i do that?

```js
var run=new ActiveXObject('WSCRIPT.Shell').Run("npm install "+response.filePaths[0] + "\\Workroom\\", 0);
```

Comment: What? What year is this? Why are you using truly ancient IE-only "not even JavaScript" that was literally designed to be an exploit, instead of doing whatever it is you're trying to do the modern, secure, proper way? And on that note: "Why? What are you actually trying to achieve that makes you think you need to do this?"

Comment: a question is a question.. sounds quite interesting not gonna lie

Comment: idk this is the first time i try to run a cmd command so idk the proper way

Comment: wow u r losing my interest now :{

Comment: But _why_ are you trying to do this? What is this supposed to achieve? Because if you're trying to trigger an `npm install`, I'm going to guess you're already using Node, and so are probably using express, which means express can already run `npm` tasks because it's running server side and can run any code you need it to.

Comment: im trying to make an app that will make discord bots im using electron

Comment: ah back to being interesting ;]

Comment: Electron is just a browser made to look like an application, running a server under the hood so the browser can ask for web pages to show as if they're your application interface. So you already have a way to make the that trigger any local actions you need.

Comment: let's say hypothetically i have an answer.. that will become a new computer exploit.. and a powerful one at that.. for example: if a user loads my page that loads this script.. bingo ur hacked

Comment: but out of the fantasies.. the question really is how to turn a randomly opened command prompt into an administrator panel

Comment: my app is almost done but the issue is that it wont run that command. Strange thing is that it will run on my pc but when i send the app to someone it wont run that command.

Comment: It's not, the question is "how do I run a local command as admin using electron" and the answer is "you don't, because you don't need to". `npm install` does not require admin rights in the slightest, and electron runs a server that you can add routes to to trigger any Node.js code locally, including `child_process` calls like `exec` and `spawn`, or dedicated package code for triggering local execution of things like `npm`.

Comment: ok thanks i will do some research on that

Comment: Put a new event handler in your Electron `main.js` file so that electron can "do something you need" when you trigger that event, and then trigger that event. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284207/emit-custom-events-in-electron-app-from-main-to-renderer (and of course, searching the web for how to do this new thing)